# Reading values from a text file using specific column numbers in Python

Tags: string, python-2.7, full-text-search, extract

If I have a large text file, and I've isolated a specific line from the text, for instance:

```
ANBL  1      2    345678    0.9   01.2  34                56.     7.8
```

Such that:

Column 1-4 = "ANBL"

Column 6-7 = " 1"

Column 10-11 = "  "

Column 13-14 = " 2",

etc.,

is there an efficient way to read information from column numbers: 6-7, 10-11, and 13-14?
    In decoding the text file, some values may be present, while other values are not. However, I know the specific *column numbers* of where information would show up, *if it were present*. A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216573/reading-specific-columns-from-a-text-file-in-python), but the accepted answer would not work in this situation since `.split()` on a string would skip over values that may contain information.

To specify, the columns are all separated by spaces, and the numbers are not the same in each line. An example of this would be comparing the following lines:

```
F014785236969    2          5  4  7.00 41.00   9    3.11         5.4         1.1
AJ51648705469    3        003002  1.60 13.00  17     7.0   6.0   5.4 20.00   2.2
```

Comment: Are spaces the only thing separating the columns? Are there always the same number of characters per line?

Comment: @LeopoldVonBushLight, I've edited my initial post in response to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If the data in your file is structured in a way so that your "columns" are always in the same character position, you can just use slices to get what you need:

```
line = "ANBL  1      2    345678    0.9   01.2  34                56.     7.8"
print(line[0:4]) # >> ANBL
```

If you know where each col starts and ends, you can define that ahead of time and do something like this (using the data from your second example as the contents of `test.txt`):

```
# Location of columns
cols = [(0,13), (17,18), (26,29), (29,32), (33, 38), (39, 44)]


with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        data = [line[c[0]:c[1]] for c in cols]
        print(data)
```

Prints:

```
['F014785236969', '2', '  5', '  4', ' 7.00', '41.00']
['AJ51648705469', '3', '003', '002', ' 1.60', '13.00']
```