# Reading columns of a txt file on python

Tags: python, text

I am working with a .txt file. This has  100 rows and 5 columns. I need to divide it in five vectors of lenght 100, one for each column. I am trying to follow this: [Reading specific columns from a text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216573/reading-specific-columns-from-a-text-file-in-python).

However, when I implement it as:

```
token = open('token_data.txt','r')
linestoken=token.readlines()
resulttoken=[]
for x in linestoken:
    resulttoken.append(x.split(' ')[1])
token.close()
```

I don't know how this is stored. If I write `print('resulttoken')`, nothing appears on my screen.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.
[part of my text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kgu7R.png)

Comment: Why do you have ' at last print? It will only print text resulttoken

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print(resulttoken)`, without the inverted commas (' ')?

Comment: Please show your "text file" as actual text, not as a graphic. There are some details, such as the separator character(s), that are not clear in the graphic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.split(' ')` is not useful, because columns of your text file separated by more than one space. Use `x.split()` to ignore spaces:

```
token = open('token_data.txt','r')
linestoken=token.readlines()
tokens_column_number = 1
resulttoken=[]
for x in linestoken:
    resulttoken.append(x.split()[tokens_column_number])
token.close()
print(resulttoken)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly now. With this I think I will manage to treat all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the file looks like to be split by table rather than space, so try this:

```
token = open('token_data.txt','r')
linestoken=token.readlines()
tokens_column_number = 1 resulttoken=[] for x in linestoken:
    resulttoken.append(x.split('\t'))
token.close()
print(resulttoken)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of five distinct lists, and append to each in turn.

```
columns = [[]] * 5
with open('token_data.txt','r') as token:
    for line in token:
        for field, value in enumerate(line.split()):
             columns[field].append(value)
```

Now, you will find the first value from the first line in `columns[0][0]`, the second value from the first line in `columns[1][0]`, the first value from the second line in `columns[0][1]`, etc.

To print the value of a variable, don't put quotes around it. Quotes create a literal string.

```
print(columns[0][0])
```

prints the value of `columns[0][0]` whereas

```
print('columns[0][0]')
```

simply prints the literal text "columns[0][0]".

Answer (score 0):

You can use data_py package to read column wise data in FORTRAN style.
Install this package using

```
pip install data-py
```

Usage Example

```
from data_py import datafile
NoOfLines=0   
lineNumber=2  # Line number to read (Excluding lines starting with '#')
df1=datafile("C:/Folder/SubFolder/data-file-name.txt")
df1.separator=","  # No need to specify if separator is space(" ") and for 'tab' separated values use '\t'
NoOfLines=df1.lines  # Total number of lines in the data file (Excluding lines starting with '#')
[Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5]=["","","","",""]  # Initial values
[Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5]=df1.read([Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)],lineNumber)
print(Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5)  # In str format
```

For details please follow the link https://www.respt.in/p/python-package-datapy.html