# How to split a txt with two columns of strings into a list?

Tags: python, string, list

I need help with something simple! I've tried different codes, but nothing worked properly.

I have a .txt file with two columns separated by space. The file looks like this:

[image: screenshot of file contents]

I want to split these strings into a list to obtain the result below:

```
my_list=['1', 'abacaxi','1','abalo','1','abalos', '0', 'abacate']
```

How can I do this?  The code below runs but the result is not what I need.

```
import os
import io
import sys
from pathlib import Path

while True:
    try:
        file_to_open =Path(input("Please, insert your file path: "))
        with open(file_to_open,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            words = f.read().lower()
            break         
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("\nFile not found. Better try again")
    except IsADirectoryError:
        print("\nIncorrect Directory path.Try again")


print('total number of words + articles: ', len(words))
corpus=words.split(' ')
print(corpus[0:20])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading columns of a txt file on python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54732771/reading-columns-of-a-txt-file-on-python)

Comment: What is the output of your example?

Comment: the output should be like: my_list=['1', 'abacaxi','1','abalo','1','abalos', '0', 'abacate']

Comment: @mkrieger1, this code did not work. I want the following result:

Comment: my_list=['1', 'abacaxi','1','abalo','1','abalos', '0', 'abacate']

Comment: Have you tried changing `words.split(' ')` to `words.split()`?

Comment: @mkrieger1. Thanks! with words.split( ) worked!!

Comment: Please don't post images of text data in your question. Put the actual text in it so other can use it for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go,

```
with open(file_to_open,'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    words = f.read().lower()

#Split the lines and join them into one line, and single spaces between them
words = " ".join(words.split(sep='\n'))

#remove double spaces with single space
    while "  " in words:
        words = words.replace("  ", " ")
#Split the line silimiter ' ' i.e. space into a list
word_li = " ".join(words.split(sep=' '))
```