# How can I import words from a document into my python file?

Tags: python, tar

[Pycharm] Hi, I am very new to programming and I wanted to make the Hangman game in python. I want to import words from the dictionary. In that way the computer chooses a random word, and the user have to guess it.

It is this video I am following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8ext9G7xspg&t=1465s

In this video she imported a words list, that she used. However I want to make one in my language. I found one online dictionary who shares their data files, and it is a tar file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygAsA.png)
The words are behind the dash - in the list. How can I retrieve only these words? and how do i import these words into my python file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQaND.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This would be a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30216573/reading-specific-columns-from-a-text-file-in-python  (if the words are always in column 3).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a good start: stackoverflow.com/questions/30216573/… (if the words are always in column 3). –
Demi-Lune
Sep 25 at 19:17